# how to check the values in both tables were same or not within postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

suppose if i am having two table likes leavedata and leavestatus in which some related columns were there (e.g. empid, refno), now i want to make the make some alterations in the leavedata table for some other columns (i.e. status). how to create a function by checking the values for both empid and refno in both tables for updating the status column

```
sample data

leavedata table

empid    refno     status  no.of days
101        1        pending      4



leavestatus table

empid    refno      check
101          1        null
```

Comment: That's a good start, but it's still quite hard to figure out what you want. A few more rows of sample data and another table showing the results you expect would help a lot. So would showing your PostgreSQL version (`select version()`) and what you've already tried.

Comment: If you're posting [new questions like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648985/how-to-insert-the-multiple-values-at-a-time-using-triggers) it's polite to please *reply to existing requests for improvement of your questions first*. Remember that *you can edit your questions* to add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit like you might want `UPDATE ... FROM`, but it's hard to say given the sparse detail.

Something like:

```
UPDATE leavedata
SET status = 'approved'
FROM leavestatus
WHERE leavestatus.empid = leavedata.empid 
  AND leavestatus.refno = leavedata.refno
  AND leavestatus."check" IS NOT NULL;
```

Massage as appropriate; you didn't define the meanings of `leavedata.check`, etc so I'm hand-waving around those. **DO NOT RUN THIS STATEMENT UNALTERED**; use it as a guide to understand what you need to do, and remember: *Always make backups* and *test statements inside a transaction so you can `ROLLBACK`*.

By the way, "check" is a terrible column name; it's a reserved word in the SQL standard, and should not be used as an identifier. You'll have to `"double quote"` it everywhere.

In future try to describe what you're trying to achieve a bit more, and if possible provide more complete sample data in an [SQLFiddle like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/18f7a/2) but with more `INSERT`s.